# How to fill in empty space with 0 using printf within Java

Tags: java, printf

How do I fill in the space of the first column in the following code with 0's?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-3.0f  %-1s%8.2f%1s %8.2f\n", (double)i, "[", 10d, "]", 10000d);
}
```

Output:

```
0    [   10.00] 10000.00
1    [   10.00] 10000.00
...
```

Ouput I want

```
000  [   10.00] 10000.00
001  [   10.00] 10000.00
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a zero in front of the print format:

```java
System.out.printf("%03.0f ...");
// -----------------^
```

Comment: Great, that worked! Thanks! Also is there another way to use an integer in the formatting? it doesn't like %03.0i... I am just converting the int to a double right now, but that doesn't seem like the best way.

Comment: @Xzar: use `%03d` for integer types.

Comment: I get an IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 0 when using d

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       System.out.printf("%-3.0f  %-1s%08.2f%1s %08.2f\n", (double)i, "[", 10d, "]", 10000d);
  }
```

See the 0 before the 8.

Comment: Is there a way to format integers for the first column? I want something like %03.0i if thats possible

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%03d  %-1s%8.2f%1s %8.2f\n", (int)i, "[", 10d, "]", 10000d);
```

Comment: When will it throw that exception?

Comment: you don't need that part, I just take the top part from some other project to test the code..